# i am using sql databse for favorite images problem is that when i click many time on same image it add many times in favorites

Tags: java, android

here is my code when i am adding images in sql databse ..

```
public long addImage(Images_model model) {
    db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cvImage = new ContentValues();
    cvImage.put(URL, model.getUrl());
    cvImage.put(FAV_ID, model.getImageID());

    return db.insert(FAVORITE_TB, null, cvImage);
}
```

and here is the code to click on favourite button on images to add in favorite..

```
  holder.fvrtButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                Images_model model = new Images_model();
                model.setUrl(image_list.get(position).getUrl());
                model.setImageID(image_list.get(position).getImageID());
                DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(context);
                long result = dbHelper.addImage(model);
               

                if (result > 0) {
                    holder.imageButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_heartfill);
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Save in Favorite", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    holder.imageButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_heart__1_);
                    Toast.makeText(context, "data failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(context, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I see in your code is work correct always add new image when click bro.

You should check `id` of image is exist in favorite list or not first. If that `id` exist in favorite list then no need to call `addImage()` method again.

Comment: String imageId = image_list.get(position).getImageID();
  DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(context);
   addToFavourites(dbHelper, model, holder);
   ArrayList<Images_model> favListStored = dbHelper.getAllFavImages();
    if (favListStored.isEmpty()) {
     addToFavourites(dbHelper, model, holder); // adds to fav...
      } else {
      for (int f = 0; f < favListStored.size(); f++) {
       if (imageId.equals(favListStored.get(f).getImageID())) {
    // exist
        } else {
            addToFavourites(dbHelper, model, holder)   }

Comment: i am trying like  in above code but its not working..

Comment: You should remove else clause in loop. Then use `flag` with `false` value outside. Loop favListStored if it exist then set `flag` value to `true`. And check `flag` at end function if it is `false` then `addToFavourites`, `true` is nothing or notification is it exist in favList